# chromecast is not playing hls stream

Tags: android, chromecast, http-live-streaming

I have a hls video stream which is not playing on the Chromecast device. I have also enabled CORS on the stream host. The video is playing on my android app.

When I open the stream link in my Chrome browser it shows following request and response headers

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

**Response Headers**

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:max-age=86400
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:89
Content-Type:application/x-mpegURL
Date:Fri, 10 Jul 2015 06:33:42 GMT
ETag:"1433735738"
Keep-Alive:timeout=10, max=100
Last-Modified:Mon, 08 Jun 2015 03:55:38 GMT
X-HW:1436510022.dop013.am4.t,1436510022.cds048.am4.c
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:cds.n2p5u8x8.hwcdn.net
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: There isn't enough info here. It is not even clear what type of receiver you are using and there is no log from the receiver to see what is happening. I suggest you be more specific and provide more debug info.